# Why I can't change the time format of a Standard user account

Tags: windows-7, date-time

In simple words we have Desktop computer with windows 7. I'm Administrator user and my wife and my daughter are standard users. So while explaining to my daughter I just looked for time in notification area on screen on which her account is logged in. It has 24hr format in it. So I tried to change the time to 12 hours format thru standard ways like right click on clock in notification area and follow the Adjust Date/time but in vain. So I thought that it might take effect after logging out and in again, restarting the computer. But that also failed to change the time format. Looking for the solution in internet but no success uptill now. So how can I change the time format?

Comment: Can you provide specifics on what prevent you from changing the time format?  Unless you apply a group policy a standard user should be able to change the time format.  Please edit your question instead of replying to this comment.  The option to change the format back to 12 H format should be in the equivalent section of Date & Time and specifically where you assigned regional format data.

Comment: I know you are here to help but this is the situation. No error displayed. If there was a error I would have chased the error. I haven't edited any group policies. I had set up parenteral control but now that is also off.

Comment: Please, edit your question, and better describe what’s preventing you have changing the regional format data.  It’s not clear what roadblock you ran into.